# Useless if statement in yum source

Tags: python, yum

I was curious about how something worked in `yum` so I was looking at some of its score code and I found this line in the `erasePkgs` function in `cli.py.`

```
if False: pass
elif basecmd in ('erase-n', 'remove-n'):
   rms = self.remove(name=arg)
.
.
.
```

The `if False: pass` does nothing correct?  It never gets into that branch it always just skips to the next one doesn't it?

Here is the link to the source code: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/master/cli.py.  It's on line 1268.

Comment: Probably was just some code that used to exist but maybe the branch got effectively "commented out" by putting in `if False`. Or maybe the developer had intentions to put something there but forgot. Who knows? It's just code rot. It doesn't do anything, as you say.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't guess what some developer intended with random junk code.

Comment: @Iguananaut Well I wanted to ask here in case there was a reason that I wasn't aware of as I am not an expert in Python and I figured there could be a valid reason for that line to exist.

Comment: Nope. None whatsoever.

Comment: Eh, I don't think we need to guess the developer's intent to answer this. Either the answer is "yes, `if False: pass` followed by `elif x: y()` is identical to just `if x: y()`", or the answer is "here is a corner case where `if False: pass` may have a sensible purpose"

Comment: @Kevin that was my intent by asking this yes, I didn't want to immediately assume it was useless.

Comment: ... That said, the most expedient path to an answer might be to log an issue on the project page asking the developer what they had in mind when they wrote it :-)

Comment: @Kevin yeah I was planning on doing that but if it was related to knowledge of Python, which I don't have a lot of, then they'd probably close my question and direct me here anyway.  Hence why I wanted to double check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be the developer's idiom for a generalized switch statement.

```
        if False: pass
        elif basecmd in ('erase-n', 'remove-n'):
            rms = self.remove(name=arg)
        elif basecmd in ('erase-na', 'remove-na'):
            ...
        elif basecmd in ('erase-nevra', 'remove-nevra'):
            ...
        else:
            ...
```

which is ever so slightly more readable than

```
        if basecmd in ('erase-n', 'remove-n'):
            rms = self.remove(name=arg)
        elif basecmd in ('erase-na', 'remove-na'):
            ...
        elif basecmd in ('erase-nevra', 'remove-nevra'):
            ...
        else:
            ...
```

Comment: Huh that's interesting, the readability doesn't seem much better/worse either way for me.  Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I suppose it's "slightly more readable" only because all the conditions have the same `elif` prefix, analogous to the way a `switch/case` in other languages has a consistent `case` prefix. But the added confusion from the first line probably negates any of that benefit, except to the original author who's familiar with his own style.